# Dropdown list to show all values

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have been working on asp.net. I have a registration form with grid view.
The grid view contains the id of dropdownlist(ddl).

> when i select the grid view ,all values have to be shown in appropriate fields in registration form.
>   For ddl, from the ddl id value in grid view ,appropriate dropdown list text is shown in dropdownlist.
>
> THE PROBLEM COMES HERE, dropdown list showing only the appropriate value and AGAIN IT CANNOT BE CLICKED AND POPULATED FOR UPDATE BUTTON

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYP1M.png).

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANYID='" + dbCompany + "'";
                txtTextBox1.Text = newcmpid;   
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                ddlCompanyName.DataSource = dt;
                ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "COMPANYNAME";
                ddlCompanyName.DataValueField = "COMPANYID";
                ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
```

HOW TO POPULATE THE DROPDOWNLIST WITH ALL ELEMENTS BY THE SAME TIME HIGHLIGHTING THE APPROPRIATE VALUE

Answer (score 1):

To achive selection just use:

```
ddlCompanyName.Items.FindByValue(dbCompany).Selected = true;
```

But You should also notice that you SQL query is dangorous. It allows to create SQL inject attack. Instead of concatenating it you should SQL params.

So the full code could be like this:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANYID=@ID;";
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = dbCompany;
 txtTextBox1.Text = newcmpid;   
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
 ddlCompanyName.DataSource = dt;
 ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "COMPANYNAME";
 ddlCompanyName.DataValueField = "COMPANYID";
 ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
 ddlCompanyName.Items.FindByValue(dbCompany).Selected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping....But showing error FindByValue(dbCompany) has invalid arguments.i am new to C#.anyother Correction to be made??

Comment: if dbCompany is an intiger use `toString` method on it